# Unable to activate EMP cannon in final mission

Tags: anno-2070

I'm on the final mission of the Anno 2770 campaign, and I am trying to disable F.A.T.H.E.R.'s shields using the EMP cannon installed on one of my ships.  However, when I left-click on the EMP cannon to activate it, nothing happens.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you click to activate the EMP item, you need to click a target.  One that hopefully most of your other ships are nowhere near, as it will disable everything within its area of effect.